# Can not displaying data from database using jquery event change to textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i need your help for solve my problem.
i have made a project for displaying a data from database using jquery onchange function. i have made the code bellow. but it not work. i dont know why.

please someone help me to solve this. i would appreciated when you give me an example for better code for my problem

**Jquery**

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#kode_mat").keyup(function() {
        var nisp = $('#kode_mat').val();        
        $.post("../php/tp_order/auto_complete.php", // request ke file load_data.php
        {parent_id: nisp},
        function(data){
             $('#material').val(data[0].nama);

        },'json'
      );
   });
   });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
        $c=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error()); // koneksi ke server database
        mysql_select_db('silo',$c)or die(mysql_error()); // pilih database

        $sql="select * from material where kode='$_POST[parent_id]'";
        $response = array(); // siapkan respon yang nanti akan di convert menjadi JSON
        $query = mysql_query($sql);     
        if($query){
            if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
                while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
                    // masukan setiap baris data ke variable respon
                    $response[] = $row; 
                }
            }else{
                $response['error'] = 'Data kosong'; // memberi respon ketika data kosong
            }
        }else{
            $response['error'] = mysql_error(); // memberi respon ketika query salah
        }
        die(json_encode($response)); // convert variable respon menjadi JSON, lalu tampilkan 

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
                <td width=70>Kode Material</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="kode_mat" type="text" name="kode_mat" maxlength="25" size="15" onkeyup="kode();" /> </td>
                <td width=1>  
                <img src="../image/edit.png"  class="button" name="edit" id="edit" style="height:35px; width:40px; " />
                <img src="../image/delete.png" class="button" name="dir1" id="dir1" style="height:35px; width:40px" onclick="up();"/>
                <img src="../image/print.png"  class="button" name="print" id="print" class="print" style="height:35px; width:40px;" />
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=70>Nama Material</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="material"type="text" name="material" maxlength="100" size="15" style="text-transform:uppercase" /> </td>
               <td width="1"><input type="text" id="no" type="text" name="no" maxlength="1" size="15" readonly="readonly"  style="visibility:hidden"/></td>

            </tr>
```

Comment: What is your error exactly?

Comment: the data can not displaying when i type a word in kode_mat

Comment: try adding a `console.log(data);` in your POST handler function and see if you recieve your data.

Comment: Shouldn't the line `$sql="select * from material where kode='$_POST[parent_id]'";`be `$sql="select * from material where kode='".$_POST[parent_id]."'";`. By the way: You should use `htmlspecialchars($_POST[parent_id])`

Comment: on jquery function?

Comment: this is beyond risky. `$sql="select * from material where kode='$_POST[parent_id]'";`

Comment: in your .php file change this line `die(json_encode($response));`  into `json_encode($response);` and try.

Comment: Use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` and add an `error:` handler to see what errors you are getting back.  Or add `.fail`, eg `$.post(...).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { ...});`   https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Comment: hmm... im getting confuse guy's
anyone can give me an example of it?
just example for jquery and the php

Comment: Where is the problem at? php or js?

Comment: my php function is fine..
i think in the js

Comment: check the browser console for js error. you should also be able to watch the requests firing in the browser and confirm they receive a response. you should really make sure the php request is working fine.

Comment: Guess what everyone is suggesting is, go through your code step by step and check whether or not the values of variables are what you expect them to be.

Comment: ok i will try that,

Comment: Learn how to use the browser debug tools - console with console.log / debugging step through with variable inspection / network to inspect requests/responses